# in powershell can I use an array to feed another array I am using to query the AD for user object attributes?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to create a PowerShell script that can update the user object attributes for a set of users with the data populated from a csv file that gets given to me by HR.  one of the problems I am running into is that the "reports to" field in the CSV just has a legal name of the persons manager, so I need to take that info and come up with the full AD path to the manager's user object as the Manager field in AD requires that format.  so I was trying to load the csv into an array and then step through each user and take the managers name and use that to look up the path to that object then set the manager attribute of the user with that path but it's complaining about expecting a string and I am giving it an array.  I am a super novice with scripting so I am not sure what the right way to do this might be. any help would be appreciated. here is a clip of what I have been working on for reference:

```
$Path = Read-Host "Please enter the path for the CSV file" function Set-ManagerAdUsers {
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$Path
    )
    Begin { 
        $CreateSAM = Import-Csv $Path | foreach {$UPN = $_."Legal First Name" + '.' + $_."Legal Last Name"; Write-Output $CreateSAM}
        $ManagerSAM = Import-Csv $Path | foreach {[string[]]$Names = $_."Reports To Legal Name" -split ','; $LName = $Names[0].Trim(); $FName = $Names[1].Trim(); $FName = $FName.Split(" ")[0];; $UPN = "$FName.$LName"; Write-Output $ManagerSAM}
    }
    Process {
        $CreateSAM | ForEach-Object {
            $CreateSAMAccount = $_
            ForEach ($ManagerSAMAccount in $ManagerSAM) {
                $ManagerSAMDS = (Get-ADUser -Filter {sAMAccountName -eq $ManagerSAMAccount}).DistinguishedName
                Set-ADUser $CreateSAMAccount -Manager $ManagerSAMDS
            }
        }
    }
} Function CreateUPN {
    Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$Path
    )
    $CreateUPN = Import-Csv $Path | foreach {$UPN = $_."Legal First Name" + '.' + $_."Legal Last Name" + '@snipesusa.com'; Write-Output $UPN}
    Import-Csv $Path | foreach {Set-ADUser -Identity $CreateUPN -Replace @{UserPrincipalName = $CreateUPN;Title = $_."Job Title";EmployeeID = $_."file #"}}
}
```

Comment: What is it that is complaining about expecting a string but receiving an array? Is that coming from your `set-ManagerAdUsers` function?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is in the function call. But I can't say for sure until I see the whole script or an error.

```
function Set-ManagerAdUsers {
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$Path
    )

    write-host $path
    }


    $path = "c:\users.csv"

    $path | Set-ManagerAdUsers
```

output:

```
c:\users.csv
```

Comment: I started this whole script over from scratch and was able to avoid this issue entirely.  thanks all for taking a look

Answer (score 0):

I started this whole script over from scratch and was able to avoid this issue entirely. thanks all for taking a look

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).